# Android tv dispatchkeyevent to listview

Tags: android, keyboard, android-listview, google-tv

I have overridden the dispatchkeyevent in my activity to control some custom UI, but now I want android to handle the key events for my list fragment.

I am able to go through the list with `listFragment.getListView().onKeyDown(event.getKeyCode(), event);` with the title in focus,
but how can I click on the up, down, and close imageviews in my row while going through each row?

Heres my list fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#25000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Edit your Playlist"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my list row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#50000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/arrows"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/up"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_up" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/down"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_down" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/arrows" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/close_button" />

</RelativeLayout>

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#50000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/arrows"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/up"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_up" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/down"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_down" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/arrows" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/close_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is this for a Google TV device or an Android TV device like your subject asks?

Comment: google tv that runs android

Comment: You might wish to provide source for your dispatchkeyevent()